# jQuery, variable for retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jQuery and I have to do it like this:

```
data = $.getJSON('/accounts/ajax/user_details/', {'user_id' : "$user_id"})
        .fail();
update_user_details(data);
```

... since if I set the callback function .done() as suggested in the official documentation, the variable 'data' seems not to be defined:

```
$.getJSON('/accounts/ajax/user_details/', {'user_id' : "$user_id"})
        .done( update_user_details(data) ),
        .fail();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: visit [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference (or an anonymous function) to `.done()`. Now you're passing the return value of the function. And there's an extra comma at the end of the `.done()` call.

```
$.getJSON('/accounts/ajax/user_details/', {'user_id' : "$user_id"})
    .done( update_user_details )    // <-- no parentheses, no comma
    .fail();
```

And, as a side note, `.fail()` by itself doesn't do anything; you have to pass it a function that handles the error.

Comment: Ok, that works. However, I think that my problem is that, in accordance to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), I thought that I had to do it as I wrote in my question.

Comment: The documentation uses anonymous functions correctly everywhere, so I'm not sure where you picked up the syntax.